# Is it really possible to call HTTP PUT using prototype

Tags: java, ajax, rest, prototypejs, http-put

I'm running `JEE6` with `glassfish v3` on `NetBean6.9` and working on `RESTful web service`.

I have jsp file which contains javascript function below.

It basically read info from `HTML input fields` and convert to `JSON format`.

Then with `onclick Ajax call`, **attempt to send JSON string using HTTP PUT method**.
(i.e. I'm trying to `UPDATE` the db record using REST)

For js framework I'm using is `Prototype1.7`

When I test the function below, it always return 404 thus "something went wrong" alert is displayed.

According to my search Prototype above 1.5 version supports HTTP PUT/DELETE methods and to do so add **_method** to the request URL like what I'm doing:

```
var url = "/resources/inventory/" + invId + "?_method=PUT";
```

This will create for instance:

```
http://localhost:8080/NoJSF/resources/inventory/123?_method=PUT
```

I looked at Firebug and console showing that the request is actually **POST**. Not sure but I believe this is because of Prototype using POST tunneling to achieve PUT method?

Also even though Ajax is being called, my Java file with JAX-RS annotated witn @POST is not even being called (@GET version is working with separate data so this is the right file) since the first line of its method that spit message is not showing up so I suspect my Ajax statement has some bug or there is something beyond my thinking.. could anyone give me hint?

```
function protoAjaxPut() {
            //get all fields value and store into json
            var invId = document.getElementById("invIdField").value;
            var invName = document.getElementById("invNameField").value;
            //put info into JSON format

            var jsonInput = JSON.stringify(new Array(invName));

            var url = "/resources/inventory/" + invId + "?_method=PUT";

            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                method:'put',
                postBody: jsonInput,
                ContentType: 'application/json',
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var responseData = transport.responseText;
                    document.getElementById('putResponseText').innerHTML = responseData;
                },
                onFailure: function() { alert('something went wrong!')}
            })
        }//end protoAjaxPut
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are tunneled:

http://dobrzanski.net/2007/04/22/using-put-and-delete-methods-in-ajax-requesta-with-prototypejs/

Comment: Yep thanks, I've already visited that site :) I had some bugs in my code that confused me too.

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned in your question, [**prototype averts PUT, DELETE,... requests**](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/ajax/request.js#L179) by default. [Some people](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/289-allow-put-delete-and-other-http-methods-on-ajax-requests) (including me) think that this is stupid behavour, but since the developer doenst seem to care about that, we have to do it by editing the request-function itself (without touching our dist of prototype.js!):

```
Ajax.Request.prototype.request = function(url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.method = this.options.method;
    var params = Object.isString(this.options.parameters) ?
        this.options.parameters :
        Object.toQueryString(this.options.parameters);

        // NOTE: THE MISSING PART WAS HERE

    if (params && this.method === 'get') {
        // when GET, append parameters to URL
        this.url += (this.url.include('?') ? '&' : '?') + params;
    }

    this.parameters = params.toQueryParams();

    try {
        var response = new Ajax.Response(this);
        if (this.options.onCreate) this.options.onCreate(response);
        Ajax.Responders.dispatch('onCreate', this, response);

        this.transport.open(this.method.toUpperCase(), this.url,
            this.options.asynchronous);

        if (this.options.asynchronous) this.respondToReadyState.bind(this).defer(1);

        this.transport.onreadystatechange = this.onStateChange.bind(this);
        this.setRequestHeaders();

        this.body = this.method == 'post' ? (this.options.postBody || params) : null;
        this.transport.send(this.body);

        /* Force Firefox to handle ready state 4 for synchronous requests */
        if (!this.options.asynchronous && this.transport.overrideMimeType)
            this.onStateChange();

    }
    catch (e) {
        this.dispatchException(e);
    }
};
```

Run this code after Prototype got inited.
Now this:

```
new Ajax.Request('42', {method:'PUT'});
```

Will cause an actual **HTTP PUT** Request ([see a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BvvbR/1/)).

Answer (score 0):

Below which using raw xml rather than using prototype works.

When I use prototype ajax call, 405 method not allowed would return, not sure why.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function simplePut() {
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var invId = document.getElementById("invIdField").value;
            var invName = document.getElementById("invNameField").value;
            //put info into JSON format

            var jsonInput = JSON.stringify(new Array(invId, invName));

            var url = "resources/inventory/" + invId;

            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                    //out = xmlHttp.responseText;
                    document.getElementById('simple').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlHttp.open("put", url, true);
            //xmlHttp.open("put", "resources/inventory/1", true);
            //xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xmlHttp.send(jsonInput);
        }//end protoAjaxPut
</script>

...html body 

 <body>
        <h1>Inventory page</h1>

        <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
            <th>id</th>
            <th>amount</th>
            <c:forEach items="${inventoryList}" var="inv" >
                <tr>
                    <td>${inv.id}</td>
                    <td><a href="" onclick="ajaxGet(${inv.id}); return false;">${inv.amount}</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
        <hr />
        <h3>REST</h3>
        <form method="post" action="">
            Inventory ID: <input type="test" id="invIdField" readonly /><br />
            Inventory Name: <input type="text" id="invNameField" /><br />

            <input type="button" value="insert POST form" onclick="protoAjaxPost()" /><br />
            <!-- <input type="button" value="update PUT" onclick="protoAjaxPut()" /><br /> -->
            <div id="putResponseText"></div>
        </form>
        <button onclick="protoAjaxPut()">update PUT</button><br />
         <button onclick="simplePut()">call SIMPLE PUT</button><br />
         <button onclick="ajaxDelete()">HTTP DELETE</button><br />
         <div id="simple"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Actually forgot that my question is regarding to prototype, ouch but its ok as long as PUT works in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank RienNeVaPlus for his answer.  I added additional override in order to post correctly with parameters and contenttype:

```
Ajax.Request.prototype.setRequestHeaders = function() {
        var headers = {
          'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
          'X-Prototype-Version': Prototype.Version,
          'Accept': 'text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*'
        };

        if (this.method == 'post' || this.method=='put') {
          headers['Content-type'] = this.options.contentType +
            (this.options.encoding ? '; charset=' + this.options.encoding : '');

          /* Force "Connection: close" for older Mozilla browsers to work
           * around a bug where XMLHttpRequest sends an incorrect
           * Content-length header. See Mozilla Bugzilla #246651.
           */
          if (this.transport.overrideMimeType &&
              (navigator.userAgent.match(/Gecko\/(\d{4})/) || [0,2005])[1] < 2005)
                headers['Connection'] = 'close';
        }

        if (typeof this.options.requestHeaders == 'object') {
          var extras = this.options.requestHeaders;

          if (Object.isFunction(extras.push))
            for (var i = 0, length = extras.length; i < length; i += 2)
              headers[extras[i]] = extras[i+1];
          else
            $H(extras).each(function(pair) { headers[pair.key] = pair.value });
        }

        for (var name in headers) {
          this.transport.setRequestHeader(name, headers[name]);
        }
      };
```

Only tested for PUT method.